# any object alloc memory for skspriteNode class for but that object type is sknode then what happen?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

my next questiion is
 if i say skspriteNode class and then say it's type to skNode then what happen ...??
is that node still can access skspritenode and anchor point of skspritenode

SKSpriteNOde *node=[SKSpriteNOde spriteNodeWithColor:[] size:];
node.anchorPoint=CGPointMake(.1,1);

[(NSMutableArray*)sarray addObject:node];

later (for SKNode *node1 in sarray)
{

SKNode *node3=node1;

then this node3 belong to anchor point (.1,1) ya (0,0)default...

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,but only by :

SKSpriteNode *sn = (SKSpriteNode *)node1;

(this is true for any class and not just SKSpriteNode)

Comment: then if [scene addChild:node3]; then it use anchor point it's anchor point (.1,1) by default in scene coordinate